# Rasa_core throwing error when running model

Tags: python

I was trying to run the example 'moodbot' from rasa_core. After training the model and running

> python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u
>   models/nlu/default/current

I am encountering this error:

> File "C:\Users\me\rasa_core\rasa_core\interpreter.py", line 236, in
>   _load_interpreter
>       from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUConfig ImportError: cannot import name 'RasaNLUConfig'

What may be the cause ? I am running python 3.5 on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (but in a different situation), and what helped me was to install a slightly older version of Rasa NLU (I was initially using the latest version because I had forked the repo). Older releases can be found here: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/releases

You are using Rasa Core, however, so I don't know if this will help.